# Different Representation of Product of Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-explanation, products

> Suppose $f=\sum_{i=0}^m f_i\cdot x^i$ and $g=\sum_{j=0}^ng_j\cdot x^j$. Then $f\cdot g$ $=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}(f\cdot g)_{s}\cdot x^s$ $=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}(\sum_{r=0}^s f_r\cdot g_{s-r})\cdot x^s$. The reader should verify, in the special case $f=c\cdot x^m$, $g=d\cdot x^n$ with $c,d$ in $F$, that reduces to $(c\cdot x^m)\cdot (d\cdot x^n)$ $=(c\cdot d)\cdot x^{m+n}$. From this fact and the distributive law in $F[x]$, it follows that the product $f\cdot g$ is also given by $\sum_{i,j}(f_i \cdot g_j)\cdot x^{i+j}$, where the sum is extended over all integer pairs $i, j$ such that $0\leq i \leq m$, and $0\leq j \leq n$. It can also be written as $\sum_{i=0}^m \sum_{j=0}^n (f_i \cdot g_j)\cdot x^{i+j}$.

I don’t really understand following step: From $(c\cdot x^m)\cdot (d\cdot x^n)$ $=(c\cdot d)\cdot x^{m+n}$ fact and the distributive law in $F[x]$, it follows that the product $f\cdot g$ is also given by $\sum_{i,j}(f_i \cdot g_j)\cdot x^{i+j}$. I have made only partial progress. By distributive law in $F[x]$ and above fact, we have $\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}(\sum_{r=0}^s f_r\cdot g_{s-r})\cdot x^s$ $=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}(\sum_{r=0}^s (f_r\cdot g_{s-r})\cdot x^s)$ $=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}\sum_{r=0}^s (f_r\cdot x^r)\cdot (g_{s-r}\cdot x^{s-r})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matrix $a_{i,j},$ $0\le i\le n$, $0\le j\le m$ we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m a_{i,j}=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}\sum_{r=0}^s a_{r,s-r} \quad (*)$$ with convention $a_{r,s-r}=0$ if $r>n$ or $s-r>m.$

The formula describes two different ways of summing the entries of the matrix. The first way is to sum the entries in each row and then add the results. The second way is to sum the entries along the lines perpendicular to the line $i=j$, and add the results. If $n=m$, i.e. we have a square matrix, the line $i=j$ describes the diagonal of the matrix.

In the special case $a_{i,j}=b_ic_j$ the first way gives
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m b_ic_j=\left (\sum_{i=0}^nb_i\right )\left (\sum_{j=0}^mc_j\right )\qquad (**)$$
In our case we have $a_{ij}=f_ig_jx^ix^j$ so  $b_i=f_ix^i,$ $c_j=g_jx^j,$ and $a_{r,s-r}=f_rg_{s-r}x^s.$ Hence applying $(*)$ we get
$$\left (\sum_{i=0}^nf_ix^i\right )\left (\sum_{j=0}^m g_{j}x^j\right )=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}\sum_{r=0}^s f_rg_{s-r}x^s (***)$$

The question can be explained also in the following way. We want to multiply two polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^nf_ix^i,$  $\sum_{j=0}^mg_jx^j,$ and then represent the product as a new polynomial. We multiply polynomials term by term obtaining  $(n+1)(m+1)$ terms of the form $f_ig_jx^{i+j}.$ Now we collect the terms corresponding to the same power of $x,$ i.e. with  the same value $i+j.$ The quantity $i+j$ ranges from $0$ up to $n+m.$ Denote $s=i+j$ and $r=i.$ Then $j=s-r$ and $f_ig_jx^{i+j} =f_rg_{s-r}x^s.$ Now we collect the terms corresponding to the power $s$ of $x,$ obtaining
$$\sum_{r=0}^sf_rg_{s-r}x^s$$ Finally we sum up over all possible $s$ and get
$$\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}\sum_{r=0}^s f_rg_{s-r}x^s$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I still can’t reconcile $\sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^m a_{i,j}=\sum_{s=0}^{m+n}\sum_{r=0}^s a_{r,s-r}$. Precisely, what is line $i=j$? And I wanna ask how do you write $a_{ij}=f_ig_jx^ix^j$ from $a_{r,s-r}=f_rg_{s-r}x^s$?

Comment: I have re-edited the answer adding a new explanation at the end. Perhaps it is more digestible. If you form the terms $a_{i,j}$ in rectangular form (as a matrix) you will see the line corresponding to $i=j.$ If $n=m$ we get a square matrix and on the diagonal you will see the terms $a_{i,i}$ that means terms for which $i=j.$

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I think, psl2Z answer is short and simple.

Comment: That's true. I had impression, that you had problems with the formula $(***)$ I do not mind if you accept the answer by psl2Z.

Comment: I’m sorry for late reply. I don’t know why lately I don’t get notification of stack exchange. Your answer is really really nice. It is not only useful for this post, but future post. Indeed I had problem with formula $(***)$.

Answer (score 1):

$f\cdot g$ $= (\sum_{i=0}^mf_ix^i)\cdot(\sum_{j=0}^n  g_jx^j)$ $= \sum_{i=0}^m ((f_ix^i)\cdot\sum_{j=0}^n g_jx^j)$ $= \sum_{i=0}^m (\sum_{j=0}^n (f_ix^i)\cdot (g_jx^j))$ $= \sum_{i,j} f_ig_jx^{i+j}$